# I'm using Django with a remote Oracle database, and getting a "Table does not exist" error

Tags: django, oracle, multiple-databases, ora-00942

Whenever I execute a simple query using the Django ORM on a table in the remote Oracle database, I get this error:

```
>>> from apps.dl.models import Article
>>> Article.objects.using('dl').all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/www/acm.local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 68, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/var/www/acm.local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 83, in __len__
    self._result_cache.extend(list(self._iter))
  File "/var/www/acm.local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/var/www/acm.local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 672, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/var/www/acm.local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 727, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/acm.local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 15, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/var/www/acm.local/server-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 507, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Here's the model I'm using:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12, db_column="ID")
    publication_id = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12, db_column="PUBLICATION_ID")
    issue_id = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12, db_column="ISSUE_ID")
    section_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12, db_column="SECTION_ID")
    title = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=512, db_column="TITLE")
    subtitle = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=512, db_column="SUBTITLE")
    page_range = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=32, db_column="PAGE_RANGE")
    start_page = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12, db_column="START_PAGE")
    end_page = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12, db_column="END_PAGE")
    article_no = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12, db_column="ARTICLE_NO")
    doi = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=128, db_column="DOI")
    publication_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, max_length=7, db_column="PUBLICATION_DATE")
    author_names = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=4000, db_column="AUTHOR_NAMES")
    sort_key = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column="SORT_KEY")
    abstract = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, db_column="ABSTRACT")
    citation_url = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=128, db_column="CITATION_URL")
    notes = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=512, db_column="NOTES")
    downloads6 = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column="DOWNLOADS6")
    downloads12 = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column="DOWNLOADS12")
    citings = models.IntegerField(null=True, db_column="CITINGS")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column="CREATED_DATE")
    short_abstract = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=4000, db_column="SHORT_ABSTRACT")
    teaser = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=512, db_column="TEASER")
    cacm_id = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=12, db_column="CACM_ID")
    cacm_ref = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=512, db_column="CACM_REF")
    cacm_only = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=1, db_column="CACM_ONLY")
    article_type = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=32, db_column="ARTICLE_TYPE")
    article_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=128, db_column="ARTICLE_TYPE")

    class Meta:
        db_tablespace = "DLDATA"
        db_table = "ARTICLES"
        managed = False
```

I've never worked with an Oracle database before, so I'm unsure as to how to debug this issue. I'm sure that my user has privileges to view the table because I can look at it using Navicat. Any hints as to how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using multiple databases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is being caused by a bug in Django. I was getting it because of the use of Schemas in Oracle. The way you get around this (for now) is:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Model stuff...        

    class Meta:
        # ...
        db_table = '"DLDATA"."ARTICLES"'
```